# Creating a framework for iOS in XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos

I am trying to create a framework in XCode 4.2 for iOS applications.

I was developing my own Game framework. I was usually distributing only in source codes and resources but, due to using ARC in my framework, I had to distribute in static library and framework.

I haven't decided which shall I use yet.
Although developing framework for iOS is not a supported way, It's better that distributing resources and headers and Mach-O file in one directory(same as framework).

So I want to use framework to distribute my Game framework.
I used this script to create a Framework.
It seems that I have success creating a framework and copy mach-O and headers and resources.
But this framework's resources couldn't be added to the application which I added this framework.

```
#!/bin/bash 

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

# Environment Variables
PANKIA_DIR="${SRCROOT}/Pankia"
PANKIA_CORE_DIR="${PANKIA_DIR}/Core"
PANKIA_PLATFORM_DIR="${PANKIA_DIR}/Platform"

FRAMEWORK_NAME="Pankia"
FRAMEWORK_VERSION=A
FRAMEWORK_VERSION_NUMBER=1.0
FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH="${SRCROOT}/build/${CONFIGURATION}-framework"
FRAMEWORK_DIR="${FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
FRAMEWORK_PACKAGE_NAME="${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.${FRAMEWORK_VERSION_NUMBER}.zip"
FRAMEWORK_TARGET_NAME="libPankia"

# Clean directories
rm -rf "${FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH}"

# Build simulator and device binaries.
xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator${IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET} -target ${FRAMEWORK_TARGET_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build
xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos${IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET} -target ${FRAMEWORK_TARGET_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build

# create framework directories.
mkdir -p ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}
mkdir -p ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Versions
mkdir -p ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Versions/${FRAMEWORK_VERSION}
mkdir -p ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Versions/${FRAMEWORK_VERSION}/Resources
mkdir -p ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Versions/${FRAMEWORK_VERSION}/Headers

# create symlinks
ln -s ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Versions/${FRAMEWORK_VERSION} ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Versions/Current
ln -s ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Versions/Current/Headers ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Headers
ln -s ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Versions/Current/Resources ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Resources
ln -s ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Versions/Current/${FRAMEWORK_NAME} ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}

# create the universal library
lipo ${SRCROOT}/build/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${FRAMEWORK_TARGET_NAME}.a ${SRCROOT}/build/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${FRAMEWORK_TARGET_NAME}.a -create -output "${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Versions/Current/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# copy files
cp ${PANKIA_PLATFORM_DIR}/GameInterface/Pankia.h ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Headers/
cp ${PANKIA_PLATFORM_DIR}/Models/Native/*.h ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Headers/
cp ${PANKIA_CORE_DIR}/Models/Native/*.h ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Headers/

cp -r ${PANKIA_PLATFORM_DIR}/Resources ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Resources/
cp -r ${PANKIA_PLATFORM_DIR}/RetinaResources ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Resources/
cp ${SRCROOT}/libPankia/Info.plist ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Resources/

# cp ${SRCROOT}/build/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/usr/local/include/*.h ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Headers/

# cp Info.plist ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Resources

# zip (配布用に TestFramework.framework ディレクトリをZIP圧縮するだけなので、配布しないなら以下はコメントアウトしてもよい)
# cd ${FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH}
# zip -ry ${FRAMEWORK_PACKAGE_NAME} $(basename $FRAMEWORK_DIR)
```

Do you know why?

And is there any better way to distribute my framework?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a helpful tutorial on creating frameworks. I have used it and have been able to package resources with the framework.

http://codefriend.blogspot.com/2011/09/creating-ios-framework-with-xcode4.html

Comment: I think I got it.
Thanks user2164 !!

Comment: I followed it and indeed, the resources are packaged inside the resulting framework. The problem is, the client app cannot see those resources which are therefore not included in the end product app. Did you have that issue?